# jQuery Navigation Assistance Needed

Tags: jquery, navigation

I have a jQuery based accordion style navigation that I am trying to modify.

It uses this code:

```
$('.interior #subContent > ul > li > a.drop').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().children('ul').toggle("slow");
    return false;
});
```

I need to be able to keep it open to the section the active page is on. I can highlight the active link with CSS, but could use some good advice for keep it open to the active section.

The navigation is as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="drop">Products</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="printing-newproducts.html">New Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="printing-inksystems.html">Ink Systems</a></li>
        <li><a href="printing-specialtyinks.html">Specialty Inks</a></li>
        <li><a href="printing-environmentalinks.html">Environmental Inks</a></li>
        <li><a href="printing-whiteplastisolinks.html">White Plastisol Inks</a></li>
        <li><a href="printing-plastisolbases.html">Plastisol Bases</a></li>
        <li><a href="printing-plastisolinkseries.html">Plastisol Ink Series</a></li>
        <li><a href="printing-pvcfreewaterbase.html">Non-PVC Water-Based
            System</a></li>
        <li><a href="printing-modifersadditives.html">Modifiers &amp; Additives</a></li>
        <li><a href="printing-completeproductlisting.html">Complete Product
            Listing</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="drop">Technical Information</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="printing-technicaldatasheets.html">Technical Data Sheets</a></li>
        <li><a href="printing-msds.html">MSDS</a></li>
        <li><a href="printing-onlinecolorcard.html">Online Color Card</a></li>
        <li><a href="printing-mixingsystemsoftware.html">Mixing System Software</a></li>
        <li><a href="printing-technicalbulletins.html">Technical Bulletins</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="drop">Tips &amp; Techniques</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="printing-tradetips.html">Trade Tips</a></li>
        <li><a href="printing-galleryoftechniques.html">Gallery of Techniques</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Note: I tried doing this with the jquery ui accordion, but I have a styling conflict with another accordion on the page among other things.

You can see it in action [here](http://projectpath.ideapeoplesite.com/rutland/printing-whiteplastisolinks.html): It is the sidebar navigation.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add a name or class to the 'li' elements so you can target the tab you want and call 'show()' on it in onready:

```
<ul>
    <li name="products" ><a href="#" class="drop">Products</a>
        ...
    </li>
    <li name="technical-information"><a href="#" class="drop">Technical Information</a>
        ...
    </li>
    <li name="tips" ><a href="#" class="drop">Tips &amp; Techniques</a>
        ...
    </li>
</ul>
```

toggle() actually calls hide()/show(), so in onready call show() on the desired 'ul'

```
jQuery(window).ready(function() {

    jQuery('li[name=products] ul').show();

});
```

Comment: Your proposed solution makes sense, but I have not been able to get it to work properly. When I click on the element the list opens but it does not open to the active action, nor can I close it again without refreshing the page.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the problem:  "I need to be able to keep it open to the section the active page is on"  I assumed this control would be on multiple pages, and the corresponding section in the list is already open.

Comment: I finally got it worked out. I took the original code that I had and modified what you added. See my final solution below. I will give you credit for the answer though because I never would have figured it out without your input. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

loop over the uls instead of mass acting on them.  If you can select an active li under the given ul, then don't shrink it.

Edit: I think this will give you close to what you're wanting, it is a little dry-coded so I'm not 100%, testing is advised.

```
$('.interior #subContent > ul > li > a.drop').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().children('ul').each(function() {
        if ($('li.active', this).length == 0) { 
            $(this).show("slow");
        } else {
            $(this).toggle("slow"); 
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Bryan, I am fairly new to jQuery. Would you mind providing a bit more detail on how that is done?

Comment: fmz: give the above code a try and see how that does for you, i wrote it in the browser here, so it may not be perfect.  Note it does require that you setup the class for the li on whatever is the active page.

Comment: Bryan, I am trying really hard to make this work. Your proposed solution makes sense, but I have not been able to get it to work properly. When I click on the element the list opens but it does not open to the active action, nor can I close it again without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

I got some really solid input from Bryan and jshali above and I wanted to post the final solution, which worked out quite nicely.

```
    $('.interior #subContent > ul > li > a.drop').click(function(){
$(this).parent().children('ul').toggle("slow");
     return false;
});

$(window).ready(function() {
$('li.products ul').show();
    $('li.technical ul').show();
    $('li.tips ul').show();
});
```

Then I add the appropriate class to the list element. It was much easier to add the class than name:

```
<li class="products"><a href="#" class="drop">Products</a>
```

Works nicely thanks for the help.